# Pay Pal - bad request error

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to get pay pal user info once he login to paypal and get authenticated by paypal.
At first step I get the **Authorization code**. But when the execution reach to get the access token of the user that will help me to get user info in next step gives me the following error.

"*Invalid Http rsponse The remote server returned an error : (400) bad 
 request.*"

I refer the  paypal documentation and sdk for donet
Fowlling is my code

```
Dictionary<string, string> configurationMap = new Dictionary<string, 
string>(); configurationMap.Add("mode", "sandbox");    APIContext
apiContext = new APIContext(); apiContext.Config =  configurationMap; 
CreateFromAuthorizationCodeParameters param = new 
CreateFromAuthorizationCodeParameters(); param.setClientId("**My 
ClientID goes here**");      
param.setClientSecret("**My Client Secert
goes here**");        
param.SetCode(code); // **Authorization code
goes here**     
Tokeninfo info =
Tokeninfo.CreateFromAuthorizationCode(apiContext,  param);   

GetUserInfor(info);
```

Please guide me where I am lacking or how can i solve this.

Comment: Next time, don't include tags in the question title. I have edited this :)

Comment: Thanks, sure I'll take care of this.

Comment: The bad request message is too broad. I'll suggest to use Fiddler to check the response contents, where you can find the exact problem the paypal api is finding